# Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': cannot import name 'is_arabic' from

Tags: python, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

When I do:
`sam local invoke MyFunction --event events/my_event.json`

I get this error:
`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': cannot import name 'is_arabic' from 'charset_normalizer.utils' (/var/task/charset_normalizer/utils.py)`

Sorry, I am not too familiar with the `aws-sam`, I have been just using a prior script and it was working fine. Any pointer would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What version of charset_normalizer is your app using?

Comment: @JohnGordon When I do `conda list` it gives `charset-normalizer 2.0.4`, so it is version 2.0.4 I think.

Another thing is that, I see couple of dirs in my folder `charset_normalizer` and `charset_normalizer-3.1.0.dist-info` that were automatically added while trying to fix another error earlier (`ERROR: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'requests'`). I have added these two dirs in my gitignore (I don't think that is the issue but just wanted to mention).

Comment: Indeed, when I try typing `from charset_normalizer.utils import`, I do not see `is_arabic` as an option. But, I am not even using this `is_arabic` in my code anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of head-scratching, this helped.

In the `requirements.txt` I had `requests==2.31.0` earlier. I changed that to `requests==2.28.1` and now the `[ERROR] ... Unable to import module 'main': cannot import name 'is_arabic' from 'charset_normalizer.utils' ...` is gone.

I still do not get why this fixed the issue, because I think I had `requests==2.31.0` earlier and I believe it had worked. However, going through the history of the `requirements.txt` (+ my notes), I had `requests==2.28.1` much earlier. So I thought of going back to `requests==2.28.1` and it helped.

Again, I do not understand why this fixed the issue. So if someone can shed some light that would be really helpful.

OR, if there is an alternative fix to this issue, kindly post.

Thank you!

Comment: I was getting the same error: `'is_arabic' import error`, and I was using `requests==2.29` then as per your suggestion I used `requests==2.28.1` but I kept getting the same silly import error unfortunately :(

Comment: I then used `charset-normalizer==3.3.2` and the problem was solved, but I got a warning:   `/opt/python/requests/__init__.py:109: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.18) or chardet (None)/charset_normalizer (3.3.2) doesn't match a supported version!`

Comment: @AlperYilmaz Good to know about the `charset-normalizer==3.3.2`. Unfortunately, not sure why you are getting that warning :(